# Unexpected behavior combining collections in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using http://console.neo4j.org as a sandbox, I have come across the following unexpected behavior:

**Statement 1 - Returns 1 row with a collection containing Neo Node**

```
MATCH (n:Crew) 
WHERE n.name="Neo" 
WITH COLLECT(n) AS c1
WITH c1+[] AS c2
RETURN c2
```

**Statement 2 - Returns 0 rows (unexpected)**

```
MATCH (n:Crew) 
WHERE n.name="Neo" 
WITH COLLECT(n) AS c1
MATCH (n:Crew) 
WHERE n.name="NoOne"
WITH c1+COLLECT(n) AS c2
RETURN c2
```

**Statement 3 - Returns 1 row containing an empty collection**

```
MATCH (n:Crew) 
WHERE n.name="NoOne"
WITH COLLECT(n) AS c1
RETURN c1
```

I fail to see why **Statement 2** is not returning the same result as **Statement 1**, because it should return a collection containing the Neo node, just like in **Statement 1**.
**Statement 3** shows that the second `MATCH` in **Statement 2** should be resulting in an empty collection.

Is this behavior expected in Cypher? If that's the case, I'd be happy about a small explanation to help me understand this behavior.

Comment: Use optional match in Statement 2, if MATCH returns no data, then (except if you have an ONLY aggregation result) it will return no rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into this exact behavior before, and it is very frustrating. The issue is with the second `MATCH` clause in Query 2: if an existing result row (in this case, your single row with `c1`) doesn't return any results for a `MATCH`, that row will be dropped completely after that `MATCH` clause, *even though* that `MATCH` on its own (without the pre-existing result row) returns an empty collection. If you convert it to an `OPTIONAL MATCH` you'll be able to keep your result row when there are no matches.

UPDATE: See below for a more thorough analysis, but the tl,dr is that the second `COLLECT(n)` in Statement 2 *does* return an empty list, just like in Statement 3; however, the whole clause `WITH c1+COLLECT(n) AS c2` returns no rows, because there are no rows with a `c1` value after the second `MATCH`.

Comment: If there's no comment from someone at Neo, I'd suggest raising an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues), though. It does look like an inconsistent behavior regarding aggregations.

Comment: I don't think it's inconsistent aggregation behavior, though; if you remove the `c1+` from Query 2's second `WITH` statement, you get a single row with an empty collection again. The `WITH` statement *as written* in Query 2 requires a row with a `c1` value to generate a new result row, of which it has 0, whereas Query 3 never requires an existing result row.

Comment: And if you remove the intermediate `WITH` (so just stack the two `MATCH` statements, then do both `COLLECTS` in a single `WITH statement`) you end up with a single empty list (since no row will fit both `MATCH`es). So the aggregation behavior is self-consistent, it's the `WITH` that's causing the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite think of the right explanation for why the 2nd query doesn't do what you expect, but if you have multiple optional matches that you want to chain together then you could use an OPTIONAL MATCH to do that:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Crew) 
WHERE n.name="Neo" 
WITH COLLECT(n) AS c1
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Crew) 
WHERE n.name="NoOne"
WITH c1+COLLECT(n) AS c2
RETURN c2
```