# cql doesnt pass node in WITH statement

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the following query to count the number of created users and create a user if the user with that id doesnt exist:

```
 MERGE (uc:UserCounter)
 ON CREATE SET uc.count = 0
 WITH uc
 MATCH (u:User{id:X})
 WITH uc, count(u) as counts
 MERGE (u:User{id:X})
 ON CREATE SET uc.count = uc.count+1, u.id = uc.count, u.creation_ts = TIMESTAMP()
 RETURN counts
```

I'm also returning counts to see if the user existed before or not. This query gives me back 
*(no rows)*. After some debugging, I came to the conclusion, that the uc node is not been passed until the end. What am I missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected behavior combining collections in Cypher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873935/unexpected-behavior-combining-collections-in-cypher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873935/unexpected-behavior-combining-collections-in-cypher/39876668#comment67045400_39876668): if the user doesn't exist yet, the `MATCH` will not return any row despite the `count()` aggregation. You'll need an `OPTIONAL MATCH` for it to work instead.

Your query seems off though: why would you match/merge on id X, then overwrite it on creation with the current count? It's also dubious it would work correctly when executed concurrently.

Comment: It works now thanks, and behind my "dubious" query is a long story ;)